# Objective-C #import a whole directory

Tags: objective-c, import, directory

Hey guys, sure hope you can help me.

I've got around 50 Model-Classes stored in a seperate Folder (not only a group) and I really don't want to write an #import for each of these classes.

Is there a way to import a whole directory?

I know it's possible within other programming languaged and perhabs I simply used wrong syntax.

Plz help me!
greets Infinite

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#import` is just a variant of `#include`. They don't allow to specify a whole directory.

You will have to specify each of your 50 header files.

You can generate that list with bash:

```
cd myfolder ; printf '#import "%s"\n' *.h > ../myheader.h
```

Answer (score 5):

As a possible workaround you can import all of them in separate header(e.g. MyImports.h) and import only it whenever you need.